# Custom outline and input text color problem

Tags: css, input, sass, outline

i got a problem in css . So when i remove the color from input , outline works as it has to , but when i add `color:white` at first it shows default outline with color white , and only then the written outline works

```css
input {
  padding: 14px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #282828;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: lime;
  outline: none;
  transition: outline-color 0.5s ease-out;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
}

input:focus {
  outline: solid;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-color: #ff5500;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Nickname..." />
```

check this out http://test-znaniya.ga

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) if you include the processed CSS rather than the SASS, along with the HTML on which it acts.

Comment: @HereticMonkey its just in form that has no primary signifance, and the app is created in  default react

Comment: I'm just recommending that you add the HTML for the `input`, and the rendered CSS. If you don't want to provide even that much help to the volunteers who are helping you find an answer, well, you don't have to...

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok, so i did as u said..

Comment: I see no problems in Firefox...

Comment: Not quite, but I've taken the liberty of adding the Stack Snippet for you. Now people here on SO can have a runnable example right here... From which I can see that that color of the outline is unchanged...

Comment: i changed from white to lime u can see how it misbehaves , i work in opera and chrome , and in either of them it works wrong

Comment: You are right, don't know whats that about, first time seeing it. Up-voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of this line:

```css
transition: outline-color 0.5s ease-out;
```

It will transition the outline-color from the current color to the new colour (#ff5500), but you have not defined a current color, so the question is "what is the default value of `outline-color` ?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-color) in the formal definition, the initial value is

"`invert`, for browsers supporting it, `currentColor` for the other"

`currentColor` will be *lime* in the example you gave.

So to recap what is happening when you focus:

1. the outline is set to *solid* with *2px* width
2. it's color is transitioned from *lime* to *some kind of red*

This can be easily fixed by simply adding a default value for the *current-color* to for example the same as the border color:

```css
input {
  padding: 14px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #282828;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: lime;
  outline: none;
  outline-color: #282828;
  transition: outline-color 0.5s ease-out;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
}

input:focus {
  outline: solid;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-color: #ff5500;
}
```